# How to get content within 4 column with proper alignment

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, slds

Trying to achieve 4 columns layout. Tried below code

```
 <lightning-card title={title} icon-name="custom:custom17">
 <!-- Current Period Logic starts here -->
 <div class="slds-box">
 <lightning-card title="test" icon-name="custom:custom17">
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
        <span>
           <p> Discount1</p>
           <p> Discount2</p>
           <p> Discount3</p>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12" >
        <span>
           <p> Discount4</p>
           <p> Discount5</p>
           <p> Discount6</p>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
        <span>
           <p> Discount7</p>
           <p> Discount8</p>
           <p> Discount9</p>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
        <span>
           <p> Discount10</p>
           <p> Discount11</p>
           <p> Discount12</p>
        </span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

result attached below:

[image]

```
  4th column is appearing below (above image discount10-12), so i changed <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12" >to <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12" >
```

Result attached:

[image]

Now I tried same logic in lightning record view form,but itsnot working as expected.

```
  <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api- 
 name="Rate_Code_and_Insurance__c">
   <lightning-card title={title} icon-name="custom:custom17">
   <!-- Current Period Logic starts here -->
   <div class="slds-box">
    <lightning-card title="test" icon-name="custom:custom17">
     <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
           <span>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_1__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_2__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_3__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
           </span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12" >
           <span>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_4__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
           </span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
           <span>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
           </span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
           <span>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
              <p>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
              </p>
           </span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </lightning-card>
```

but itsnot working as expected:

Is it because of help Text? how to get content within the column with proper alignment?

Comment: It looks like it's working exactly as you've defined it.  There are 4 columns.  Your problem is the content in your columns is funky.  Maybe your question should be how to get the content within your column to align as required.

Comment: thank you. updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all that span/p stuff to make the grid work. Just place your elements directly as you'd like them to appear left to right.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_1__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_2__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_3__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_4__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-size_3-of-12" field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
</div>
```

Note that it is more idiomatic to use lightning-layout and lightning-layout-item:

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_1__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_2__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_3__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_4__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="3">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Discount_5__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox. still itsnot working . added the screen shot in the question

Comment: 4 columns are coming properly but texts are trimming @sfdcfox.

Comment: @Annappa That's the way `lightning-output-field` works.  It's a set width for the label/value areas.  I'd suggest this answer is exactly what you're after.  If you want a different layout, perhaps ask a new question about how to control the layout of your  data.

Comment: @Nice hook I will just wait for sfdc fox or any other suggestion for trimming. otherwise ill open new question  better to get answer in one place.it will helpful for other searching for similar contents

Comment: @Annappa You can try adding `slds-form-element_stacked` to the elements, or use `variant="label-hidden"` if you don't need the labels.

Comment: @sfdcfox I need those labels

Comment: @Annappa So use stacked labels.

Comment: i tried same . it works @thanks sfdcfox :)